# what is the purpose of "export as namespace foo"?

Tags: typescript

I'm using some `*.d.ts` files and I see in many of them the following two lines:

```
//foo.d.ts
export = foo;
export as namespace foo;

declare var foo;

[...]
```

I can understand that in the former one (`export = foo`), `foo` is the thing exported. But what is the meaning of `export as namespace foo`? How should it be consumed or used from the outside?

In the case of react ambient declaration file, it says:

```
export = React;
export as namespace React;

declare namespace React {
[...]
```

Can't the React namespace be exported with:

```
export declare namespace React { [...]
```

?

Comment: You sould read this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-umd-module-definitions

Comment: So if you put export as namespace all the global stuff in the file will be seen from the outside like it is defined inside a namespace. And at the same time, if you don't use modules, you will have direct access to all the globals. Right?

Comment: Not all of it, but everything exported via this namespace (if your using it as an UMD module).

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I have understand based on this doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#umd-modules

When you write `export as namespace React;` in a declaration file (`*.d.ts`) you are telling that `React` can be used to access the whole exported content as a global variable inside a script file.

A script file is a typescript file without `export` or `import`, so it can be used for example within a `<script src="yourFile.js">` inside a browser.

Note that this only works if you also export something, in this case `export = React` tells to export the namespace.

`export declare namespace React` is not equivalent because for commonJs it doesn't export as the `default` and for script file it just doesn't work (doesn't add the namespace to the global variables).

For you own module if you expect to use only `commonjs` I suggest to avoid using namespaces and just use `export ...` or `export default ...` if you have just one export.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44849515/209727
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html