# Explain "export =" and "export as namespace" syntax in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make use of the type declarations files in the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository. Many of these files use the following pattern:

```
export = React;
export as namespace React;
```

Googling around, I've found references to this being used to make a declaration file usable in both module-based and non-module-based systems. However, I'm struggling to find a clear explanation of:

1. what each of these lines exactly does individually and
2. how exactly this combination works to support both types of consumers.

Comment: Hmm... [Seems you're not the first to have this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44554883/215552). Not a dupe, since that one wasn't answered either. You might consider tagging this with react as well to see if react experts know.

Answer (score 54):

The first form is used for CommonJS and AMD module systems. You have to match the `export = React` with `import React = require('./React')`

See the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) which gives this example:

ZipCodeValidator.ts

```
let numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
class ZipCodeValidator {
    isAcceptable(s: string) {
        return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
    }
}
export = ZipCodeValidator;
```

Test.ts

```
import zip = require("./ZipCodeValidator");

// Some samples to try
let strings = ["Hello", "98052", "101"];

// Validators to use
let validator = new zip();

// Show whether each string passed each validator
strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(`"${ s }" - ${ validator.isAcceptable(s) ? "matches" : "does not match" }`);
});
```

The `export as namespace` form creates a global variable so it can be used without importing, but you may still import it with the `import { name } from "some-library"` form of import. See the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#umd-modules) which gives this example:

math-lib.d.ts

```
export function isPrime(x: number): boolean;
export as namespace mathLib;
```

The library can then be used as an import within modules:

```
import { isPrime } from "math-lib";
isPrime(2);
mathLib.isPrime(2); // ERROR: can't use the global definition from inside a module
```

It can also be used as a global variable, but only inside of a script. (A script is a file with no imports or exports.)

```
mathLib.isPrime(2);
```

Here you have a generic type library which doesn't know which module system is being used so it tries to cover all bases.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I had read these two samples before posting. I still find myself unsure of the meaning of "but you may still import it with the `import { name } from "some-library"` form of import". What is `name` in this example? Specifically, when both `export =` and `export as namespace` are used together, what are the implications for `import from` style imports?

Comment: @Duncan, how would one extend mathLib namespace, but also keeping it in the global scope (no module augmentation)

Comment: @AlexandruC, no idea. Post that as a separate question?

Comment: @AlexandruC the link is broken